# MySQL JSON_LENGTH Query Optimization

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, audio

I have stored Audio-Segments as base-64 encoded arrays in JSON format in MySQL database, and now for loading them into memory I want to divide them by batch_size - for that I need to calculate JSON_LENGTH for all audios (400) in memory at runtime. The original audio is converted from bytes to base-64 encoded strings via another service which cannot be altered at the moment to also store its size when inserting into DB.

My problem is that when I run:

```
SELECT JSON_LENGTH(row) FROM TABLE;
```

it takes a very long time to run, and that impacts our performance alot. Is there an alternative way of calculating the length of JSON_ARRAY datatype in MySQL in real-time?

Comment: You may add stored generated column into table structure with this expression and use this pre-calculated value. It will be recalculated automatically each time when data altered, and may be even indexed. Of course insert/update become slightly slower. See [CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html), [ALTER TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html).

Comment: Yea I already mentioned that theres no way that I can change the current table structure at the moment - so really need a way to calculate this speedily at runtime.

Comment: *I already mentioned that theres no way that I can change the current table structure at the moment* Does this table already exists statically? Or this "another service" is re-created this table each time when it saves data? If first then added column will interfere with this service actions hardly... Can you test?